# algorithm for mathematical recursive function

Tags: java, algorithm

I had got a problem below I tried but failed to get solution hence seeking your help.
The function GF is defined as follows

```
GF(A,B,0)=A
GF(A,B,1)=B
GF(A,B,N)= GF(A,B,N-1)+GF(A,B,N-2) where N>1
```

Given 3 non negative numbers A B N returns remainder from division by `1000000007`

```
For example given A =3 B=4 n =5 the function should return 29 BECAUSE
GF(3,4,0)= 3 mod 1000000007 = 3
GF(3,4,1)= 4 mod 1000000007 = 4
GF(3,4,2)= (GF(3,4,0)+GF(3,4,1)) mod 1000000007 =7
GF(3,4,3)= (GF(3,4,1)+GF(3,4,2)) mod 1000000007 =11
GF(3,4,4)= (GF(3,4,2)+GF(3,4,3)) mod 1000000007 =18
GF(3,4,5)= (GF(3,4,3)+GF(3,4,4)) mod 1000000007 =29
```

space complexity O(N) time O(Nlog N)

I am looking how to approach this java pseudocode or solution I tried from 4 to 5 hrs but not able to move ahead hence seeking your help

Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am looking how to approach this java psedocode or solution I tried from 4 to 5 hrs but not able to move ahead

Comment: Then please post your attempts and explain what the problem with your solution is.

Comment: @chiru Where are you stuck? Can you give a naive implementation you tried, and the reason it does not work?

Comment: Come on, these are just generalized Fibonacci numbers. There is plenty of code for that; just take any regular Fibonacci calculation program and change the base.

Comment: Its not fibonacci I think its something to do with recursion but not able to start

Comment: Here is a starter: [Fibonacci Dynamic Programming solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Fibonacci_sequence)

Comment: Where did `1000000007` come from, and why is it not in your recursive definition?

Comment: 1000000007 is a constant  number on which function is applied

Comment: For info: 1000000007 is the biggest long int prime number, by using modulo it allows to keep the results within the limit of the memory while keeping the property of the calculations involved.

Now after scratching my head a bit I found a relatively good answer, since the question is closed I will answer here.

At first I wrote a recursive function quickly, but this will not answer the space complexity O(N).

Comment: Then use a loop like amit, but this will not answer the time complexity O(log N).

So I tried to find a pattern and got that:
```
GF(A, B, 0) = 1A + 0B
GF(A, B, 1) = 0A + 1B
GF(A, B, 2) = 1A + 1B
GF(A, B, 3) = 1A + 2B
GF(A, B, 4) = 2A + 3B
GF(A, B, 5) = 3A + 5B
GF(A, B, 6) = 5A + 8B
GF(A, B, 7) = 8A + 13B
```
If you look closely you will see that the factor of A and B follow the Fibonacci number, you can then deduce that:
`(Fib(N - 1) * A + Fib(N) * B) % 1000000007`

So you get one formula to find the result , answering both complexity.

PS: there are formulas for Fibonacci

Answer (score 9):

I will provide you hinters on how to solve it, it is your homework and you should learn from them.

1. use an array of size `n`. Let it be `arr` (`int[] arr = new int[n]`)
2. First, initialize `arr`'s first 2 elements with `a,b`: `arr[0] = a % 1000000007 ; arr[1] = b % 1000000007 ;`
3. Then iterate from 2 to `n` using a for loop : `for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)`, and for each iteration set `arr[i] = (arr[i-1] + arr[i-2]) % 1000000007;`
4. At the end, your last element of the array - is the desired one.

Wrap it all up and you get your answer. Good luck.

Comment: That is not recursion...

Comment: @BwithLove **The question does not ask for recursion**, it just defines the funciton recursively and asks how to solve it efficiently - **O(n) time**. The title says `algorithm for mathematical recursive function`. The mathematical function is recursive, the solution does not have to be. Save your rage downvotes for where it belongs.

Comment: @BwithLove Where does the question mention recursion? I see a mention in comments, but just a "I think it has something to do with..."

Comment: `algorithm for mathematical recursive function [on hold]` that is title.

Comment: @BwithLove Yes, exactly. The mathematical function is defined recursively, the algorithm is not asked to be recursive nowhere in the question nor title. Stop raging and accept being wrong on occasions is human.

Comment: Actually, there is no need for an array `arr`, which can create out of memory exception for large value of n, nice solution though :)

Comment: Upvoting this answer. Having a recursive function is cute but will create a stack overflow